# how to install android studio in linux mint 19 64-bit

Tags: android, android-studio, linux-mint

should i also install 32 bit libraries ?

```
sudo apt install -y libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386 wget
```

I am using a 64 bit os.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official website](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux) you need to install the 32-bit lib:

> Required libraries for 64-bit machines:
>
> If you are running a 64-bit version of Ubuntu, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
> ```

To enable multi-arch :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```